# Get the value of toggle switch jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile

When the submit is pressed I want to alert the value of the switch, however it is not working as planned

jsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Q3p9X/

JS

```
$('#newevent1info').submit(function (event) {
    var val = $('#newevent1').slider().value;
    alert(val);
}
```

ALSO for some reason its creating a slider in my header:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use `val()` not `value`

check this [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/vladkras/u4Wga/1/)